# Parameters for CART tree

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, matlab

I'm using fitctree function from Matlab to fit a CART tree to my dataset (10'000 data points, 20 features).

First, how can I exactly prune it and to what level should the tree be pruned? I think I have to use the prune method but I'm confused by the 'MergeLeaves' and 'Prune' flag.

Second, what values of 'MinLeafSize', 'MinParentSize' and 'MaxNumSplits' is reasonable to try?